# Extending a function defined in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ to a continuous function defined in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Let $g: \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^{1}$ and suppose that there is $M > 0$ such that
>   $$\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}g(x)\right| \leq M.$$
>   Prove that if $n \geq 2$ then $g$ can be extended to a continuous function defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that if $n = 1$ the statement is false.

**My attempt.**

I define the extension $\bar{g}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\bar{g}(x) = g(x)$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\{0$} and $\displaystyle \bar{g}(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$. Thus
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \bar{g}(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = \bar{g}(0),$$
so $\bar{g}$ is continuous. So the question is reduced to proving that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$ exists. Thus, I must show that
$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0\text{ s.t. } \Vert X \Vert < \delta \Longrightarrow |g(x)|<\epsilon.$$

The hypothesis
$$\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}g(x)\right| \leq M$$
seems necessary for getting
$$|g(x)-g(y)| \leq M|x-y|$$
using the Mean Value Inequality. This almost solves the problem, because if $g(0) = 0$ we can write
$$|g(x)| \leq M|x|.$$
But $g(0) = 0$ doesn't make sense. I'm stuck here.

Also, I cannot see why it is necessary that $n \geq 2$, where I use this in the demonstration, and why it fails when $n=1$.

Comment: $f(x) = x/|x|$ would be a counter-example for $n=1$. I *assume* that the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} $ for $n \ge 2$ plays a role.

Comment: The problem is to show that the limit exist... To show abstracly that the limit exists, use sequential caracterisation and show the sequence is a cauchy sequence with your mean value inequality. If n=1 the mean value inequality fails. Do you see why ?

Comment: @DLeMeur, I think fails because $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is disconnected, as Martin said. We can define $f(x) = -1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$. Then we can find $x,y$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| = 2$ but $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @DLeMeur Using your hint. Take $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{n} \to 0$. By Mean Value Inequality, $|g(x_{n}) - g(x_{m})| \leq M|x_{n} - x_{m}|$. Since $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy, $g(x_{n})$ is Cauchy. This, $g(x_{n}) \to L$. Therefore, $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = L$.

Comment: Yes. But you can t conclude directly the convergence of $g $.You must also show that L does not depend of $(x_n)$.

Comment: All right! I will try.

Comment: @DLeMeur Suppose that $g(x_{n}) \to L_{1}$ and $g(y_{n}) \to L_{2}$. Given $\epsilon>0$, take $n_{0} = \max{n_{1},n_{2}}$, then $n>n_{0}$ implies $|L_{1} - L_{2}| \leq |g(x_{n}) - L_{1}| + |g(y_{n}) - L_{2}| < 2\epsilon$ ($n_{1}$ is of the convergence of $g(x_{n})$ and $n_{2}$ is of the convergence of $g(y_{n}$)). Is correct?

Comment: To have the MVI apply to $|f(x)-f(y)|,$ you need to know $[x,y]$ does not go through $0.$

Comment: There is a third term that you have forgotten in your inequality : | g (x_n) - g (y_n) |. But it is still possible to majorate it. (There was also an other method : introduce $(z_n)$ that coincide with $(x_n)$ on even indices, and with $(y_n)$ on odd indices).

Comment: @zhw. yes! I will use your answer!

Comment: @DLeMeur oh, its true! It was a lack of attention. Thank you for the hints!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose $x,y\ne 0.$ Let $L$ be the line through $x$ and $0.$ If $y$ is not on $L,$ then $[x,y]$ does not pass through $0.$ Hence $|f(y)-f(x)|\le M|y-x|$ by the MVI. If $y$ is on $L,$ Choose $y'\ne 0$ close to $y$ but not on $L \,...$